# Xamarin android No resource identifier found for attribute in package

Tags: android, xamarin, drawer

I'm currently working on an android core app using xamarin, I have installed android support design 23.4.0.1, and Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 23.4.0.1

And the problem I'm having right now is in this lines:

```
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@layout/menu_navigation"
```

With the error "No resource identifier found for attribute in package"

I was reading some of the questions already answered in here, but still can't fix the error, maybe because I'm using xamarin, I don't know.

Full code in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/drawer"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:openDrawer="start">
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.learn2crack.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include
        layout="@layout/listitem_device" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@layout/menu_navigation"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Note: I was using this tutorial: https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/android-material-design-sliding-navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Instead of:

```
</android.support.v7.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now my code works.

Answer (score 1):

**Change this:**

```
xmlns:app|xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

**To this:**

```
xmlns:app|xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.app.chasebank"
```

and build

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the `app:` namespace ontop of your control?

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: Yes I have it on top

Comment: Can you post the full build output in your question?

Comment: Yes, I just did it.

Comment: That is not the build output. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27515/how-to-obtain-diagnostic-build-logs (XS) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx (VS)

Comment: Sorry! I read that too fast I didn't realize, but for the good news I manage to make it work, I just changed:</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
to:
</android.support.v7.widget.DrawerLayout>
and worked